# Messages from queues or subqueues

Tags: msmq

I want to create  just a one queue with messages from three different persons, so I just want to take out  the messages from the queue only those which are from person one, I need to modify them and take back to the queue. Someone told me that maybe I could use sub-queues but I'm not sure about how to use that…

This is the method to send to the queue

```
private void btnEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   System.Messaging.Message mn = new System.Messaging.Message();
   Persona p = new Persona()
   { 
     Codigo = 100, 
     Nombre = "Jose Luis Naranjo"
   };

   mn.Body = p;
   mn.Label = "Msg: " + c.ToString(); 
   mq.Send(mn)
}
```

Comment: Can you include some code that you are using? It's hard to help you without seeing what you have attempted.

Comment: Thanks Juan Carlos,  this is the  method to send to de queue            private void btnEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          
                System.Messaging.Message mn = new System.Messaging.Message();
                Persona p = new Persona() { Codigo = 100, Nombre = "Jose Luis Naranjo" };
                
                mn.Body = p;
                mn.Label = "Msg: " + c.ToString();               
                mq.Send(mn)}

Comment: Please include that code in your original question with the appropriate formatting so that it is more readable.